# How to get error using the Microsoft Api Graph using the Java SDK

Tags: java, error-handling, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

In the microsoft documentation you can see the following example:

```
graphClient.teams(teamId)
.buildRequest()
.patch(team);
```

but what happens if the operation is not performed correctly and I want to query the error returned, is there any way to know if the operation failed and get the cause of the error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Java but for .NET you can [send HTTP request](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/overview.md#send-http-requests-with-the-net-microsoft-graph-client-library) and read a response status code.

There should be similar way for JAVA.

Comment: yes, you can do that, but I would like to do something similar with de Java SDK, not using http request.

Answer (score 0):

It will throw a [ClientException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.graph.core.clientexception?view=graph-core-java) if the operation is not performend correctly. You can then check the Error Message.

For example if no team with the id is found it wil look somthing like this:

```
 Error code: Request_ResourceNotFound
 Error message: Resource 'exampleTeams' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.
```